# Virtual machine installation is mandatory for Hadoop

Tags: software-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop. To install multi node Hadoop2.7.2 does this require virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Hadoop web page, the Open Source version requires **Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 7.x - 64-bit (Docker 1.10+)**. The Enterprise version can work on Windows 10, Mac OSX, or RHEL.

Sounds like you'll need a virtual machine like Virtualbox, running RHEL, at minimum. I'd recommend doing more research to see if Virtualbox is realistic to run this, based on available resources.

If you're dual-booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu, installing under Windows 10 might provide better results.

Cheers, Al